# Laravel Scout (meilisearch) with Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, meilisearch

I am trying to use Laravel `Scout` with docker I followed along with the docs [Laravel Scout Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout)
I made all required steps for installation and everything is up and running as expected. but whenever I try to search data I received this error `cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7720: Connection refused`. I am sending the request from `insomnia` to `laravel` route web.

- **Note**:- when I visit http://127.0.0.1:7720/ the meilisearch default page shows up. also tried to `curl -kvs --http2 --request GET 'http://localhost:7720/indexes'` it works fine and returns `Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7720 (#0)` but whenever I send from `insomnia` I got the error

steps to reproduce the error

1. trying to search `Event` model by keword `PENDING`.

   `\App\Models\Event::search('PENDING')->get()`
2. Event model class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Database\Factories\EventFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Event extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    use Searchable;

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $keyType   = 'string';

    protected $fillable = ['event_type_id', 'status'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->id = Str::uuid()->toString();
        });
    }

    public static function newFactory(): EventFactory
    {
        return EventFactory::new();
    }
}
```

3. Laravel `.env` file

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:7720
MEILISEARCH_KEY=masterKey
MEILISEARCH_NO_ANALYTICS=false
MEILISEARCH_NO_SENTRY=true
```

4. docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: app:latest
        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www/
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        networks:
            - app-network

    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: db
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
            - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        networks:
            - app-network
        ports:
            - 3307:3306

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - app-network

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: pma
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 8283:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOSTS: ${DB_HOST}
            PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
            PMA_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            PMA_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        networks:
            - app-network

    meilisearch:
        image: getmeili/meilisearch:latest
        container_name: meilisearch
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 7720:7700
        environment:
            MEILI_NO_ANALYTICS: ${MEILISEARCH_NO_ANALYTICS}
            MEILI_NO_SENTRY: ${MEILISEARCH_NO_SENTRY}
            MEILI_MASTER_KEY: ${MEILISEARCH_KEY}
        networks:
            - app-network
        volumes:
            - ./meilisearch-data:/meilisearch-data

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the issue was that I am using `meilisearch` as a docker service so I should specify the `MEILISEARCH_HOST` env variable to point to the service name like `DB_HOST=db` (docker service name). so in this case I changed the `MEILISEARCH_HOST` from `MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:7720`  to `MEILISEARCH_HOST=meilisearch:7700` now everything is working fine as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting the same error while tryint to run `artisan scout:import "App\Models\Foo"` and couldn't figure out what was going on. Your solution worked for me!

Comment: Glad to hear that <3

Answer (score 3):

Since your Meilisearch's service is called "meilisearch", could you try `MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7720`?

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score -1):

Brother, first thing first, the container isn't exposing environment variables. If you can specify something like `env_file` or use the `secrets` methodology then you can access your environment variables inside the container. And, the environment variables like `SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:7720` aren't assigned to any of the services. Maybe that's preventing it to initiate.

Comment: If I got you, you mean my defined env variables are not  used by the container, if this is what you mean, I tried to check the env variables inside the container and it's already there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add this into your .env file

`MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7720`

Answer (score -2):

I noticed you’re making an external API request to a route in the `web.php` and that might be the cause of your problem. Setup your routes in your `api.php` and try again